# Cannot open Gallery to delete files, due to running out of space

Tags: gallery, insufficient-memory

I have a rather funny though annoying problem. I've filled the memory of my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 up with photos, videos, apps and offline maps, and now I have a "Not enough storage space" warning. I would like to delete the photos and videos I do not need, but when trying to open the Gallery, I get a message "Not enough space. Delete unnecessary items such as ... pictures, videos..." So I need more space to run Gallery to free some space. Any workaround?

Comment: Have you checked with the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? There you'll find some first aid. Quick hints: Use a file manager if you've installed one, otherwise (temporarily) remove one or more "less important" apps.

Comment: @Izzy, thanks but all that it mentioned in the wiki I already know. I have 70 MB free (i.e. >25 MB stated in the wiki). Plus the question is basically about the Gallery problem, I think I did not make it clear enough. I am not sure why it cannot even start (if each photo is on the order of a few megs). Anyway, the hint about the file manager is worthy. Maybe you could post it as an answer. Please indicate the path where photos/videos are stored by the Camera.

Comment: The camera files are generally stored at /sdcard/DCIM/Camera on a phone whose camera option for storage has not been changed. Otherwise, the camera settings will still lead you to the storage location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While several hints can be found in the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), you case seems a little special ­– as you report to still have ~75 MB free (3 times the limit this error should be triggered).

This should even enable you to install a file manager (if you have not already done so, or a useful file manager was pre-installed). So in order to remove some photos/videos, you could start the file manager and look into the "usual locations". I've put that terminus in quotes, as different apps seem to place them into different locations.

Most photo apps save their images below `/sdcard/DCIM`, many use their own folders here. But as that is not related to your "phone storage" (SDCard, whether internal or external, should never trigger that issue), there might be a similar folder on *phone storage*. Irritates me a little, but I've read that before a few times. So make sure to use a file manager supporting this (alternatives below). Next to the `DCIM` folder, also check `Pictures`, `Photos`, `Video`, `media`, `Music`, and `Documents`, if they exist.

A good alternative to "local" file managers (apps that is), there's always the option of using ADB (if you've not yet installed it, check out [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)). In case you're not used to the Unix/Linux command line, tools like [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/download/) might come in handy, offering a graphical file manager (amongst other things). On a rooted device, and with the help of [adbd Insecure](http://www.appbrain.com/app/%5Broot%5D-adbd-insecure/eu.chainfire.adbd), you could even access the entire file system this way (careful!).

Answer (score 1):

I was running out of space, not even to be able to run Gallery to delete contents.

Try the "My Files" app to manage all files (images, videos, music, and documents.) Go to My Files > clear your cache and clear your data > then go to Gallery and delete photos and videos.

Comment: Could you mention the link of this app?

Comment: My Files app is the standard file management app with most Samsung Galaxy devices. Its simplistic, with low overhead, because of its rudimentary features. If you can't find it in your app drawer, you may have disabled it in favor of something stronger? Look for it in Application Mangement, possibly in the disabled tab/section.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into your files, you will see a photos and videos sign. Click on that and it should say `delete`. If it does, click it and choose which ones you would like to delete.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to uninstall some applications that are huge in size.
In this way the internal storage can be freed enough to open the gallery app without insufficient memory error.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to "NO space to draw images" while opening the Gallery is to connect it to a computer via USB then delete all unwanted photos from the Gallery and/or all WhatsApp images. Even delete other videos and audio files in the WhatsApp folder (if applicable).

I tried this and it works every time.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. The solution is very easy. Try these three alternatives.

1. Stop running apps that you aren't using. You have to stop them from the Settings - App manager. Now try to open your gallery.
2. If it doesn't work, simply reboot your phone and open your gallery to delete files.
3. If these two don't work, take a backup of your phone (better to PC) and restore the phone to the factory setting.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I hope this will work for all of you.

Go to Settings, Storage and then format the USB storage as this may be the reason why Gallery could not be opened as it is eating up the internal storage capacity of your phone .

I have tried hard reset but still this USB storage was seemed not wipe out.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings/Storage/Pictures & videos and start to delete items. After you delete a few, you can then go to the camera and now access it normally.

Answer (score -2):

Open Gallery, tap settings, select content to display, deselect Picasa and they will magically disappear.  Where they go, I don't know.  But they're no longer in my Gallery!!!!

Comment: I'm not so sure this will work since OP already said he couldn't open Gallery in the first place.  That said, this looks like hiding the photos from displaying, not deleting them, thus not sure how it will fix the "out of space" issue.